# serialization compatible change mentioned in specification, appears to be incompatible

Tags: java, serialization

Referring to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678 
At the bottom of the page, it is mentioned(copied):
*Changing the access to a field - The access modifiers public, package, protected, and private have no effect on the ability of serialization to assign values to the fields.*

But when I change access modifier of a field and deserialize, it fails.

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

private String name; //later change this to protected, public or remove access modifier, all are failing

public Person(String name){
    this.name=name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person{ name= "+name+"}";
}
```

}

```
public class PersonTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person person = new Person("Thor");
    try (ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get( "thor.ser")))) {
        stream.writeObject(person);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Person anotherPerson = null;
    try (ObjectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("thor.ser")))) {
        anotherPerson = (Person)stream.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(anotherPerson);
}
```

}

when i add serialVersionUID of serialized class to Person class, it works fine.
Since this is a compatible change, it should pass without adding serialVersionUID.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: In addition to above rule, below mentioned compatible changes are also failing. Rules:
Adding fields
Changing a field from static to nonstatic or transient to nontransient

Comment: Are failing how?

Answer (score 0):

'Compatible change' means that an old serialized stream can be understood by an `ObjectInputStream` using the new class definition, and *vice versa*. See [#5.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#a6678), first two paragraphs.

It does not mean that the `serialVersionUID` doesn't change. Almost anything can cause that.